# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'interface' of 'require(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript

While testing the solidity contract, I'm getting the error

```
`const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');
        ^
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'interface' of 'require(...)' as it is undefined.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\91960\lottery\test\Lottery.test.js:6:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:334:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:331:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:809:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:108:16)
    at exports.runMocha (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:142:13)
    at Object.exports.handler (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:292:3)
    at Object.runCommand (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1113:24)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:575:25)
    at Object.exports.main (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:68:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\91960\lottery\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha:162:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 `
```

Here is the `compile.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'utf8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Lottery'];
```

Here is the `Lottery.test.js` file:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let lottery;
let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
});

describe('Lottery Contract', () => {
  it('deploys a contract', () => {
    assert.ok(lottery.options.address);
  });

  it('allows one account to enter', async () => {
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether')
    });

    const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call({
      from: accounts[0]
    });

    assert.equal(accounts[0], players[0]);
    assert.equal(1, players.length);
  });

  it('allows multiple accounts to enter', async () => {
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether')
    });
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[1],
      value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether')
    });
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[2],
      value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether')
    });

    const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call({
      from: accounts[0]
    });

    assert.equal(accounts[0], players[0]);
    assert.equal(accounts[1], players[1]);
    assert.equal(accounts[2], players[2]);
    assert.equal(3, players.length);
  });

  it('requires a minimum amount of ether to enter', async () => {
    try {
      await lottery.methods.enter().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: 0
      });
      assert(false);
    } catch (err) {
      assert(err);
    }
  });

  it('only manager can call pickWinner', async () => {
    try {
      await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({
        from: accounts[1]
      });
      assert(false);
    } catch (err) {
      assert(err);
    }
  });

  it('sends money to the winner and resets the players array', async () => {
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether')
    });

    const initialBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({ from: accounts[0] });
    const finalBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    const difference = finalBalance - initialBalance;

    assert(difference > web3.utils.toWei('1.8', 'ether'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you show your solc / solcjs versions ? Your example doesn't follow the current API : https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc

Comment: My current solidity compiler is 0.8.10

Comment: @AnayDongre The compile.js file is too old, it should look like the one in this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/114000 for solc 0.8.

Answer (score 0):

check the solidity version in the contract file and package-json file both versions should be the same, if not then download the specific version by the following command.

```
npm install solc@your_version_of_solidity
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give `solc.compile` a JSON input as in the github documentation for solcjs v0.8.10.

Also `solc.version()` will give you your version of solcjs in the node runtime to make sure.